# Не срабатывает transition при добавлении класса с помощью element.classList

Tags: javascript, css3, css-animation, transform, transition

есть слайдер `

```
<div class="slider_item slider_item-block></div>
              <div class="slider_item></div>
              <div class="slider_item></div>
```

`

стили scss `

```
.slider_item {
               display: none;
               transform: scale(0.1,0.1);
               transition: transform 2s;
               &-block {
                  display: block;
                  transform: scale(1,1);
               }
```

`
и js - переключает классы

```
slideItem[index].classList.remove('slider_item-block');
slideItem[++index].classList.add('slider_item-block');
```

переключение происходит моментально, не пойму в чем дело.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

display: none; замени на opasity: 0;

почитай здесь, если что переводчик поможет смисл понять
[Transitions on the display: property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331353/transitions-on-the-display-property)

Comment: а как скрыть другие елементы?

Comment: visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;

Comment: так и сделал, а чтобы visibility: hidden места не занимали зделал им position: absolute. норм решение?

Comment: более логично height: 0; width: 0;